# Is it ok to post a question on both StackExchange and another software specific forum at the same time?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [How do you configure Confidant to use the Access Key Id/Secret Access Key for its IAM user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/786060/how-do-you-configure-confidant-to-use-the-access-key-id-secret-access-key-for-it)

I've seen a couple users post a question and leave a note, with a link, at the bottom stating that they also asked the same question on another forum. Is that allowed here? I've personally found it helpful in cases where the question was answered on one forum and not the other. But if it's frowned upon I won't make a habit of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should never, ever crosspost to another StackExchange site, but 3rd party sites are OK (in my opinion).